# varnish+nginx+php-fpm good combo?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish

does having varnish as a reverse proxy/cacher with nginx backend for dynamic content a good idea? im looking for a way to really speed content up when dealing with a ddos or get flood.

Answer (score 1):

Using varnish for caching is a really good idea since varnish was designed for caching. You will get a specific caching policy description language, proper statistics and logging, some tracing capabilities. I prefer to use varnish for caching and nginx for other tasks (like FastCGI proxying in your case).